# If $f \in C^{(2)}([-L,L])$, then \exist a constant M > 0 that satisfy certain property.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

If $f \in C^{(2)}([-L,L])$, then $\exists$ a constant M > 0 that satisfy:
$$|c_{n}(f)| \leq \frac{M}{n^2}.$$

where $c_{n}(f)= \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L} f(x) \overline {g_{n}(x)}dx,$ and $g_{n}(x) = e^{in\pi x/L},$ for$ L>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: This is false: For example $f(x) = x$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ gives $c_n$ on the order of $1/n.$ You may want to assume $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ with $f$ $2L$-periodic.

Comment: You will need an additional assumption (periodicity  or compact support for $f$, e.g.) but then you can just integrate by parts twice to prove the claim.

Comment: How did you calculate this sentence "For example $f(x)=x $ [−π,π] gives $c_{n}$ on the order of $1/n$"?

Comment: @User8128  the question said do this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288724/a-property-about-the-fourier-coefficients-of-a-continuously-differentiable-funct   then deduce  what I stated above in my question, How can I deduce? I think you mean integrating by parts twice to $c_{n}(f)$ not $c_{n}(f')$ so what is the relation between the two questions? I can not see, could u clarify this for me please?

Comment: @Idonotknow I will add an answer explaining my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f \in C^2[-L,L]$ and that either $(i)$ $f$ is periodic $[$so that $f(-L) = f(L)$ and $f'(-L) = f'(L)]$ or $(ii)$ $f$ has compact support inside $[-L,L]$. Then by integrating by parts, we see \begin{align*} c(f) &= \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L f(x) e^{-in\pi x /L} dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2L}\int^L_{-L} f'(x) \frac{e^{-in\pi x/L}}{-in\pi/L} dx + \frac{1}{2L}\left[ f(x) \frac{e^{-in\pi x/L}}{-in\pi/L} \right]_{x=-L}^{x=L}\\
&= \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^L f''(x) \frac{e^{-in\pi x/L}}{(-in\pi/L)^2}dx -\frac{1}{2L}\left[ f'(x) \frac{e^{-in\pi x/L}}{(-in\pi/L)^2} \right]_{x=-L}^{x=L} + \frac{1}{2L}\left[ f(x) \frac{e^{-in\pi x/L}}{-in\pi/L} \right]_{x=-L}^{x=L}.
\end{align*} Now $$\frac 1{2L}\left[ f(x) \frac{e^{-in\pi x/L}}{-in\pi/L} \right]_{x=-L}^{x=L} =  \frac{1}{-2i\pi n}[f(L) e^{-in\pi} - f(-L)e^{in\pi}] = \frac{(-1)^n}{-2i\pi n}[f(L) - f(-L)] = 0$$ by our assumption and similarly for the other boundary term. Thus \begin{align*}\lvert c(f) \rvert &= \left \lvert\frac 1 {2L(-in\pi/L)^2} \int^L_{-L} f''(x) e^{-in\pi x/L} dx
\right\rvert \\
&\le \frac{L}{2\pi^2 n^2} \int^L_{-L} \lvert f''(x) \rvert dx.
\end{align*} Thus we can take $$M = \frac{L}{2\pi^2}\int^L_{-L} \lvert f''(x) \rvert dx $$ $($which is finite since $f \in C^2[-L,L])$ and we have $$\lvert c(f) \rvert \le \frac M{n^2}.$$

Comment: so f must be periodic so that the two terms of the integration cancel each other ? but if f has a compact support what will happen to the terms of the integration?

Comment: If it has compact support in $[-L,L]$ then $f$ and all it's derivatives are zero at the end points so those terms go away.